# Need Help understanding this piece of MySQL Code

Tags: mysql, database

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
`ID` int(10) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL auto_increment,
`username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`),
KEY `Username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

what is
a) unsigned, zerofill in ID table?
b) what do you mean by KEY `Username` (`username`) ?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unsigned = a none positive / negative number, so you couldnt have -1 as the "-" is a sign.

zerofill = fill it with zeros by default. Not necessary as the column's already got the auto_increment / pk attributes

key = index this column i.e. make SELECTS that search on this column faster.

Ta

Comment: a none positive / negative number - hmmmm, does that mean it's an imaginary number ??

Answer (score 3):

zerofill - left pad with 0

> For example, for a column declared as INT(4) ZEROFILL, a value of 5 is retrieved as 0005.

---

unsigned is number not less than zero

> If you specify ZEROFILL for a numeric column, MySQL automatically adds the UNSIGNED attribute to the column.
>
> Unsigned type can be used to permit only nonnegative numbers in a column or when you need a larger upper numeric range for the column

details : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html

---

> KEY Username (username) ?

is an index name after `Username` on column username

details : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html

Answer (score 0):

here is a partial answer.

a) unsigned means that the value is positive.

b) zerofill means that it will have leftpadding with '0'

ex : without zerofill you have 55 and with you will have 00000055

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Zerofill is used to pad a number with zeros instead of spaces. In this case, the number 1337 would be padded with 6 zeros and shown as 0000001337 because of int(10). Specifying unsigned is not needed since zerofill automatically chooses unsigned, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html

KEY foo (bar) creates an index on the bar column. The name of the index is foo.